# remove border of navigation bar for few view controllers

Tags: ios

I want remove border of navigation bar. I am using this code in AppDelegate.m

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]
                              forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny
                                  barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

and it works well. It removes border of navigation bar in every view controller. 
But i have to remove it for few view controllers.

By placing this code in viewWillAppear of particular view controller, its not working.
Does anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: You should set the background image and shadow image of the navigation bar in your select navigations bars and not to use the appearance method. e.g.: ` [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]`

Comment: thanks....now its working :)

Comment: I'm going to add an answer with my comment so you can accept as answer and close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the background image and shadow image of the navigation bar in your select navigations bars and not to use the appearance method. e.g.:

```
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```